# whenever i change account active field related case status field should be changed to working..please help me out with this

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger AccRecCase on Account (after update) {

 map<id,account> oldMap=Trigger.oldMap; //old records ids
 map<id,account> newMap=trigger.newMap; //new record ids
    List<Id> ids=new List<Id>();

    set<id> keys=newMap.keySet();
    for(Id k:keys){
        if((Trigger.oldMap.get(k).Active__c != Trigger.newMap.get(k).Active__c) && Trigger.newMap.get(k).Active__c=='yes' ){
           ids.add(k);
        List<case> cList=new List<case>();
     List<Account> acc=[select id,name,Active__c from account where id in : ids];
            List<case> c1=[select id,status from case where accountId In : acc];
            for(case c:c1){
                c.status='working';
                cList.add(c);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you need to correct in your code:-

1. You are doing Soql query inside for loop. There is a governor limit that enforces a maximum number of SOQL Queries and if a query is inside a FOR loop, that governor limit is reached inefficiently and unnecessarily. If a query is inside a FOR loop, a query will be executed for each iteration of the loop. But to write more efficient and scalable code, its ideal to move the SOQL query outside of the for loop and retrieve all the necessary data in a single query.
2. You are not updating case after making a change in the status field
3. A slight change in your logic as SOQL on Account is not required at all
4. Using the set instead of the list to store the id to avoid duplicates by any chance

This should work fine:-

```
trigger AccRecCase on Account (after update) {

    set<Id> ids=new set<Id>();
    for(Id k:trigger.newMap.keySet()){
        if((Trigger.oldMap.get(k).Active__c != Trigger.newMap.get(k).Active__c) && Trigger.newMap.get(k).Active__c=='yes' ){
            ids.add(k);
        }
    }
    if(!ids.isEmpty()){
        List<case> c1=[select id,status from case where accountId In : ids];
        for(Case c : cl){
            c.status='working';
        }
    update cl;
    }
}
```

The above code is storing the account id as per the condition and querying the cases related to those accounts and making the change using another for loop on the queried Case record.

You should go through the best practice mentioned here:- ["Apex Code Best Practices"](https://developer.salesforce.com/index.php?title=Apex_Code_Best_Practices&oldid=26951)

Comment: +1, although #4 is not necessary in this case; the ID values for a list of records in a trigger will already be unique, so no duplicates would exist.  The difference in performance is insignificant either way, though.

Comment: Thanks, @sfdcfox for pointing out.